# (Java, BricxCC) Unable to create process bash

Tags: java, compilation, bytecode, lego-mindstorms

I would like to get a .rxe file (Mindstorms Bytecode) from a .java file. I downloaded BricxCC but every time I try to compile my test.java with the program, I get an error message:

```
Unable to create process:
bash "C:\Program Files (x86)\BricxCC\test.cmd"
Make sure bash is in a directory on the system path or in the same directory as the
controlling program (C:\Program Files (x86)\BricxCC\).
```

I tried modifying the Java compiler settings in the preferences but everything looks fine. Does anyone have an idea?

(This guy has the same problem : http://www.sluse.com/view/20935057)

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Downloading](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/)

> (Optional) **To enable RCX brickOS C/C++/Pascal support and leJOS Java
>   support you can now download an all-in-one [setup executable](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/bricxcc/BricxCCSetupCygwin.exe?download) which
>   installs a small subset of cygwin along with pre-built H8 tools**. NOTE:
>   If you get an error when you try to run the installer that it is
>   missing BricxCCSetupCygwin.002 that means the download did not
>   complete successfully. Please try to download it again during off-peak
>   hours or using a download manager utility of some sort. Once you have
>   successfully downloaded and installed the cygwin configuration and H8
>   compiler tools then install the [minimal brickOS and leJOS](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/bricxcc/BricxCCbrickOSleJOS.exe?download) for BricxCC
>   and you are ready to go (except for leJOS, which still needs to have a
>   separately installed Java Developers Kit).

The Cygwin subset includes bash. Did you download and install this optional version?

Comment: Ok so I downloaded the setup executable and I copied everything from C:\cygwin\bin to C:\Program Files (x86)\BricxCC but it still doesn't work. However the error message is different : Compile/Download Failed Unknown GNU error code (-128). And when I try to compile from cmd with the command nxj -r test.java, I get this : http://notepad.cc/share/4NBDHkebTZ

Comment: Cygwin doesn't like being moved. Try adding c:\cygwin\bin to the front of your path.

Comment: What do you mean by that? (+ I just realised that even without moving the files from cygwin, I get this second error message)

Comment: Did you also download and install http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/bricxcc/BricxCCbrickOSleJOS.exe?download?

Comment: Yes I did and I just re-installed it to be sure but I still got the same error :/

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas :/